# Finding elements that do not overlap between two vectors

Tags: r, overlap

I'm trying to identify elements which are not included in the other vector. For instance in two vectors I have

```
list.a <- c("James", "Mary", "Jack", "Sonia", "Michelle", "Vincent")

list.b <- c("James", "Sonia", "Vincent")
```

is there a way to verify which people do not overlap? In the example, I would want to get the vector result that contains Mary, Jack, and Michelle.

Any suggestions will help!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, there is a way:

```
setdiff(list.a, list.b)
# [1] "Mary"     "Jack"     "Michelle"
```

Comment: Just be aware that all the functions in this group (setdiff, intersect, union, etc) will ignore duplicates.  If you have lists with duplicate values, you'll have to play around a bit.  In fact there was a SO question, well answered, for just this problem a couple days ago. -- which of course now I can't find :-(

Comment: @CarlWitthoft if you look at the source for `setdiff` you'll see that it's easy to modify to not ignore duplicates

Comment: @hadley I posted a 'flexible' version of setdiff, just FYI :-)

Answer (score 39):

I think it should be mentioned that the accpeted answer is is only partially correct. 
The command `setdiff(list.a, list.b)` finds the non-overlapping elements **only if these elements are contained in the object that is used as the first argument**!.

If you are not aware of this behaviour and did `setdiff(list.b, list.a)` instead, the results would be `character(0)` in this case which would lead you to conclude that there are no non-overlapping elements.

Using a slightly extended example for illustration, an obvious quick fix is:

```
list.a <- c("James", "Mary", "Jack", "Sonia", "Michelle", "Vincent")
list.b <- c("James", "Sonia", "Vincent", "Iris")

c(setdiff(list.b, list.a), setdiff(list.a, list.b))
# [1] "Iris"     "Mary"     "Jack"     "Michelle"
```

Comment: Exactly what was happening to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

An extended answer based on the comments from Hadley and myself: here's how to allow for duplicates.

Final Edit:  I do not recommend anyone use this, because the result may not be what you expect.  If there is a repeated value in `x` which is not in `y`, you will see that value repeated in the output.  But: if, say, there are four `9`s in `x` and one `9` in `y`, all the `9`s will be removed.  One might expect to retain three of them; that takes messier code.

```
mysetdiff<-function (x, y, multiple=FALSE) 
{
    x <- as.vector(x)
    y <- as.vector(y)
    if (length(x) || length(y)) {
        if (!multiple) {
             unique( x[match(x, y, 0L) == 0L])  
              }else  x[match(x, y, 0L) == 0L] 
        } else x
}

Rgames> x
[1]  8  9  6 10  9
Rgames> y
[1] 5 3 8 8 1
Rgames> setdiff(x,y)
[1]  9  6 10
Rgames> mysetdiff(x,y)
[1]  9  6 10
Rgames> mysetdiff(x,y,mult=T)
[1]  9  6 10  9
Rgames> mysetdiff(y,x,mult=T)
[1] 5 3 1
Rgames> setdiff(y,x)
[1] 5 3 1
```

Comment: I would store a temporary to the result of the `if` statement, and call `unique` on that in the case `!multiple`.  It would be easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

A nice one-liner that applies to duplicates:

```
anti_join(data_frame(c(1,1,2,2)), data_frame(c(1,1)))
```

This returns the data frame {2,2}. This however doesn't apply to the case of 1,2 in 1,1,2,2, because it finds it twice